# Scale y-Axis in kibana 4.1.0

Tags: kibana-4, elastic-stack

In kibana 4.1.0 Is there some way to scale the Y-axis?, I have an average metric with a field that is in seconds, but I want it to be shown in hours, I mean the 25,000 seconds should be somenthing like 25000/3600 or something like that.

[image]

Kibana 4 provides a feature to introduce a Json input taht should be merged with the existing configuration but I cannot make it work, I saw that this script should work :

{'script':'(_value)/3600'}

but it doesnt, it throws an error :

Visualize: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[leNBGA9VRmuUiPaMidqeVw][logstash-2014.05.20][0]: SearchPar...

any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solition for this here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//modules-scripting.html

You have to add this to your elasticsearch.yml:

script.inline: on
script.indexed: on

and use this :{'script':'(_value)/3600'}